# Equation to create a mix of items taking into account starting quantities

Tags: combinatorics

Apologies if the title isn't very clear I'm struggling on how to name this question.

The problem I'm trying to solve is that I have a 4 different products and I have a different quantity of every item.

I need to place these product into bags of two whilst avoiding placing the same colour in a bag twice. 
$$
\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline Red & Blue & Green & Yellow \\ \hline 4811 & 3020 & 594 & 1764 \\ \hline  \end{array}
$$
The above table shows an example of the quantities I could be working with.

From this example we have 4 products, this means there is 6 possible unique combinations.

RB, RG, RY, BG, BY and GY.

How can I work out what combination of each back I should make?

Any help greatly appreciated. As this is my first question I've asked on here if I need to provide any further detail etc please let me know.